# How to increase my power slots in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Like the image, how to use all the powers I purchased from the pharmacy in Normandy?  I mean how to add all to my power bar and use them in combat

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to drag the powers to the slots or how to use all powers at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible. You can only select one bonus power.

The powers you see in the above screenshot are your squadmates' powers, from the console version of the game. (PC has it at the bottom).

For the record, that screenshot is from Mass Effect 1...

Comment: Good catch on the ME1 screenshot.  Where is that, Virmire?